# How to change the annotation of a clickable bar plot

Tags: pgfplots

Reading the manual always helps, but in this case it hasn't been very fruitful. I have created the following stacked bar plot. The bars are clickable (only in acrobat pdf). I would like to be able to change the value shown to the value of the segment of a bar and the symbolic co-ordinate). How can this be achieved?

```
\documentclass[oneside,sffamily]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.clickable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{bar/.style ={ybar,draw=white,fill=blue!20}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/annot/printable=false}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[
    width=1.05\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textheight,
    bar width=25pt,
    %nodes near coords,
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,
    enlargelimits=0.08,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-.30)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Technicians},
    symbolic x coords={Jul 14, Aug 14, Sept 14, Oct 14, 
        Nov 14, Dec 14, Jan 15},
    xtick = data,
    title = {\textbf{Resource Histogram.}},
    x tick label style={yshift=-5pt,rotate=0},
    ]
% Duct Erectors
\addplot +[bar] plot coordinates {(Jul 14, 165) (Aug 14,200) 
  (Sept 14,200) (Oct 14, 250) (Nov 14,250) (Dec 14,250) (Jan 15,200)};
% Pipe Fitters
\addplot+[ybar, fill=black!60, draw={white}] plot coordinates {(Jul 14,150) (Aug 14,150) 
  (Sept 14,160) (Oct 14,200) (Nov 14, 200) (Dec 14, 250) (Jan 15,250)};
% Insulator
\addplot+[ybar, fill=black!30, draw=white] plot coordinates {(Jul 14,70) (Aug 14,60)
  (Sept 14,80) (Oct 14, 80) (Nov 14, 80) (Dec 14,85) (Jan 15, 76)};
% Plumber
\addplot+[ybar, fill=black!20, draw=white] plot coordinates {(Jul 14, 167) (Aug 14,200) 
  (Sept 14,200) (Oct 14,200) (Nov 14,300) (Dec 14,300) (Jan 15,300)};
% Electricians
\addplot+[ybar, fill=black!10, draw=white] plot coordinates {(Jul 14, 184) (Aug 14, 300) 
  (Sept 14,350) (Oct 14, 400) (Nov 14,450) (Dec 14, 500) (Jan 15, 565)};
% Staff
\addplot+[ybar, fill=black!7, draw=white] plot coordinates {(Jul 14, 126) (Aug 14, 132) 
  (Sept 14,135) (Oct 14, 140) (Nov 14,140) (Dec 14, 135) (Jan 15, 120)};

% legend
\legend{ Duct Erectors, Pipe Fitters, Insulators, Plumbers, Electricians, Staff}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also any suggestions on styling will be most welcomed.

[image]

Comment: actually there is a section about `clickable coords` in the manual but my system doesn't allow for `\thisrow` usage even after converting your data to a table

Comment: @percusse Thanks. I also had a look at the js file, but there are no pointers there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clickable coords` is the best available solution here - but it applies only if you hit the position where a plot mark would appear. If you miss that position, the popup will merely show the axis coordinate, i.e. it will be unrelated to the plot(s) as such.

So, the short answer is: bar plots have only very limited support in the clickable library. More precisely: the clickable lib will only provide insight to plot marks, not to the bars.

What you need would be a feature request and requires implementational effort in both document level javascript and TeX (the latter only because we need the heights for each bar).